# ActiveSupport::Concern `to_liquid` overriden by `liquid_methods`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, liquid, operator-precedence, activesupport-concern

I have a model `Widget`.

I `include SomeConcern`

`SomeConcern extends Activesupport::Concern`
Thats all fine. I can call the methods defined in `SomeConcern` like to_liquid and everything is peachy.

Once i call `liquid_methods :foobar` within the `Widget` class, the `to_liquid` method from my concern is overridden by the default one for liquid.

How can I get my concern version to take over precedence?

Answer (score 0):

liquid uses `define_method :to_liquid` when you call `liquid_methods` in your model.

you you want your mixin to take precedence you have to include it AFTER that call.

another thing you can do is have a regular module (that is always preferable over `ActiveSupport::Concern`) and use `prepend` to put it in front of the ancestor-chain.

Comment: I did try reversing the order of inclusion to no avail.

Comment: yeah, reversing the order does not work. that's because of the way rubys class lookup works. have you tried to `prepend` it? otherwise you can use `alias_method_chain`

Comment: I ended up working around the problem a different way. Thanks for your input phoet.